# XML compare two nodes, if equal then proceed with mappings

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, webservices-client, ibm-datapower

I have to match number with ph.No other condition.

Xml temp1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/json jsonx.xsd">

   <json:array name="phoneNumbers">

      <json:object>

         <json:string name="ph">1111</json:string>

         <json:object name="custdetails">

            <json:string name="id">11333</json:string>

            <json:string name="customername">bob</json:string>

         </json:object>

      </json:object>

      <json:object>

         <json:string name="ph">111</json:string>

         <json:object name="custdetails">

            <json:string name="id">1133</json:string>

            <json:string name="customername">brb</json:string>

         </json:object>

      </json:object>

      <json:object>

         <json:string name="ph">222</json:string>

         <json:object name="custdetails">

            <json:string name="id">1</json:string>

            <json:string name="customername">bxb</json:string>

         </json:object>

      </json:object>

   </json:array>

</json:object>
```

XML temp2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<GetResponse>

   <customers>

      <customer>

         <id>1</id>

         <telephones>

            <telephone>

               <id>1</id>

               <number>111</number>

            </telephone>

            <telephone>

               <id>2</id>

               <number>222</number>

            </telephone>

         </telephones>

      </customer>

      <customer>

         <id>2</id>

         <telephones>

            <telephone>

               <id>11</id>

               <number>1111</number>

            </telephone>

            <telephone>

               <id>22</id>

               <number>2222</number>

            </telephone>

         </telephones>

      </customer>

   </customers>

</GetResponse>
```

Comment: What is your specific question or problem statement?